# Convert formatted text in Excel cells into HTML

Tags: html, excel

I have in Excel file with some cells with formatterd text (like colour and cartridge return). I need to export this text and display it into a web page, but I loose the format in the process.

Is it possible to convert the contents of the cells into HTML?

So for example a text in bold will be converted to '**text in bold**'

And a carriage return will be converted to '1st line
2nd line'

Thanks

Comment: Please have a look here it has Instructions regarding what you want to achieve:
http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/674-excel-export-to-html.html
Also this guys here has a VB script to achieve that:
http://www.calvert.ch/maurice/2012/01/13/convert-excel-to-html-with-formatting/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using VBA in Excel it is possible to access the formatting of a cell and then write the appropriate HTML to build up a web page and then save that.
Or you can do a 'Save As' and select .htm as the file type. This will result in a web page that is chock full of MS formatting but it looks quite reasonable in FF and IE.

Comment: Thanks Dan, I'll give it a try in VBA and see if I can manage the conversion to HTML. Save as it is not an option for me as I have to pickup the HTML code and save it somewhere else.